# Why are outgoing e-mail alerts not sending?

Tags: email, alert

I have a strange problem with outgoing alerts e-mails on our SP 2010 farm. Alert notification are delivered, but no alerts comes whatever I do. I remembered the page for [SP alerts here](http://sharepointalert.info/troubleshooting-sharepoint-alerts/) and followed the instructions, but with any luck...

Nothing was changed on Exchange or Configure outgoing e-mail settings in CA, server was restarted three times, no errors in log, Immediate Alerts job works (end with succeeded status every 5 minutes), owstimer is healthy and telnet SMTP test was successful.

There is one strange thing. I wanted to check if exist some aletrs waiting to be send on disk in inetpub folder, but I cannot find any. Where are they? Yes, there is chance, that we lost them... Beside that, there is no our-portal.domain folder, only old one with different DNS name and yes, we changed DNS names three days ago.

Comment: So, did SharePoint stop sending these mails three days ago? Or did the problem occur earlier?

Comment: Related question: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/2653/immediate-alerts-email-notification-not-sending-emails/2810#2810

Comment: AlexPoint about half day later I think, it is difficult to investigate exact time, because DNS changes was during sunday and there is no entry in logs at all. It works before that.

Comment: Kit Menke thank you, I saw this question, but I think this is different, because we did some DNS changes (even this change should not affect it, because IP addresses are the same) and it affect whole portal (15 collections and all application). But yes, maybe I was wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's solved for now. "stsadm.exe -o setproperty -url https://our-portal -pn alerts-enabled -pv true" command typed many times WITHOUT manually started imm. alert jobs works. Maybe it is my fault, when no alerts come in 5 minutes, I opened CA, start job manually, do some changes and type command again. If I leave it alone at the end, it works. Or maybe it is a coincidence and farm was confused by DNS changes.

Answer (score 2):

I finally fix this after following steps

- in my case initial confirmation emails was sending but future change alerts were not
- allowing all sharepoint servers in the farm to relay email in Exchange server fix the problem
- you can also change the **prefered Server** for Timer service for each Content database in central admin (/_admin/CNTDBADM.aspx)
- also note that the server which **Immediate** and **Daily** alerts are sending from, are shown in central admin. play with services and you will find it is running on your one of your servers (/_admin/ScheduledTimerJobs.aspx) .

http://sharepointalert.info/2009/11/troubleshooting-sharepoint-email-alerts-check-email-setupinfrastructure/

[image]
http://sharepointalert.info/troubleshooting-sharepoint-alerts/

Answer (score 0):

which Exchange version do you use?
did you try to configure sharepoint for outgoing smtp server with it's ip address and port 25?
check your ip config, try a telnet to the smtp server with port 25
and check technet info on http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263462.aspx

Comment: Would the alert notification work, if outgoing email settings or IP configuration are wrong?